# Finding rows where Customer appears multiple times

Tags: sql

I've obtained what I thought was the correct code for this but it's not producing any results. Take this dataset

```
    Job No, Customer
    123     Mike
    124     Mike
    125     James
    126     James
    127     Bob
```

If a customer appears more than once in the table I want my query to list ALL the jobs for that customer.  So my report would show all the jobs for Mike and James (4 records in total) but no jobs for Bob. I've tried this..

```
    SELECT JobNo 
    from tblJobs
    GROUP BY JobNo 
    HAVING COUNT(Customer) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select j.*
from (select j.*, count(*) over (partition by customer) as cnt
      from tbljobs j
     ) j
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, I realise I need to make it a little more complicated. There is another column that I need to group by (So if the values in Column B and Column C are the same (and they appear multiple times) I want to list every record that matches it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JohnCassell . . . No, that does not make sense.  This answers the question that was asked here.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by on the basis of Customer instead of JobNo

```
SELECT JobNo 
from tblJobs
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING COUNT(Customer) > 1
```

And if there is full join constraint then above query will give you error for JobNo in select, so you can use Group_concat, like -

```
group_concat(JobNo)
```

Above will give you jobNo comma separated